# How is Facebook Chat Heads implemented?

Tags: android, facebook

The [Facebook Android Messenger application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca) has a feature called Chat Heads.  It lays a chat icon and window over the top of other applications.  How is this achieved?  Which Android APIs are used?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Search for permission `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` and `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`.

See [this blogpost](https://codingshark.wordpress.com/2015/02/01/how-to-draw-on-top-of-other-applications/?utm_source=androiddevdigest) by [Daniel Jankowski](https://codingshark.wordpress.com/) and his [WindowHead sample](https://github.com/mollyIV/android-samples) on GitHub.

In addition to the duplicate answer already listed, also see:

- [Having application running above other app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266959/having-application-running-above-other-app)
- [Disappearing facebook chat heads](http://debuggingisfun.blogspot.com/2013/06/disappearing-facebook-chat-heads.html)

Comment: Is that used in gmail app also? for composing new mail

Comment: @EbinJames I don't think so. Do you mean the Floating Action Button? Maybe this is what you have in mind: https://github.com/shell-software/fab

Comment: https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/springy-heads might be useful.