# how to show a drop down like face book chat head in android

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I need to show a drop down view when user clicks on icon.
[image: same like image i have to show![enter image description here] ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIpym.png)

How can i design please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this:

[How is Facebook Chat Heads implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995297/how-is-facebook-chat-heads-implemented)

[What APIs in Android is Facebook using to create Chat Heads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads)

The one which I refered is

http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/

http://myandroidtuts.blogspot.in/2013/05/facebook-chat-heads-feature.html

You can bring the ICon on Home screen and based on the click event you can attach more Views to the same.

Comment: thank you for fast reply ...which view i can attach popwindow or diloag fragment.. if i am attching popwindow how can i made home screen black shade and how to change height of pop window rereading to key board visibility.

Comment: my question is how to add multiple view to window manager i tread frame layout and relative layout, But how can i move chat head from one place to another place if i am using relative layout.