# What type / kind of Overlay / Floating widget does the following app use: Facebook Messenger, MusixMatch, Link Bubble, LastPass

Tags: android, ios, overlay, floating

I am trying to study on how Overlay/Floating widgets works on android.

What type/kind of overlay/floating widget does the following app use. 
A brief explanation on how it works would really help.

1. Facebook Messenger
2. MusixMatch
3. Link Bubble
4. LastPass

Comment: I'm not sure what you're fully asking, but if you mean the Chat Heads for Facebook Messenger, then this is where you can start. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995297/how-is-facebook-chat-heads-implemented

Comment: and perhaps a better one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads

Comment: Thank you @DeeV for your comment.  Let me rephrase the question. What are the difference  between the overlays / element / API used by the following app:  Facebook Messenger, MusixMatch, Link Bubble, LastPass

Comment: I can't answer your question, but thought it worth pointing out that Link Bubble is being rebranded as 'Brave' and is now open sourced here: https://github.com/brave/browser-android