# Show Dialog box in another application and bring on front on top of other application

Tags: android, dialog, android-activity, android-linearlayout

I am sending data from one application to another by using aidl. The application which sends the data is in front and the application which receives the data shows a dialog box to the user is in background. Now problem is that the dialog box is not visible until i switch back to that application. Is their anyway i can show the dialog without switching back to other application. Like a battery low dialog from android which comes on top off everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

// get the context from the currently running task
List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = manager.getRunningTasks(1);
Context context = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
```

I'm not too sure if this actually works for activities that are not from your application, but I haven't got the resources to test it myself at the moment, before adding this as answer. 
It's worth a try if you actually are able to retrieve the current top activity with this. I just hope my memory gave me the right syntax...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `WindowManager` , the application which receives the data should have a `background service` . If you are posting a broadcast event to pass data to other application, then when the application receives the data , start a service to display the dialog.

The `dialog` can be a custom dialog , which need to be added as a view to `WindowManager`

Ok, Here is a sample with a custom dialog. You can try same approach with the default `AlertDialog`

When the application receive the event  , start the service and In `Service` when `onStartCommand`  called , show the dialog.

Follow this steps…..

Get the instance of `WindowManager`

```
     WindowManager  windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
```

Inflate the  custom view

```
     View dialogView = View.inflate(getBaseContext(),R.layout.dialog_layout,null);
```

Add listener to the view.

```
  dialogView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                windowManager.removeView(dialogView);
                dialogView = null;
            }
        });
```

Set `Window manager params`

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

     params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER;
```

Add the view to `Window Manager`

```
   windowManager.addView(dialogView, params);
```

Also add `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission in manifest

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to add following permission to your manifest file to achieve what you want: 

android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

Answer on following StackOverflow thread provides an example of how to do this:

[Having application running above other app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266959/having-application-running-above-other-app)