# How to make an overlay in a Browser like Chrome in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

So i have a fancy APP on android where you can store bookmarks from your browser via the "share" Button. When you share the page, the APP saves the browsed page (here comes my question) and displays the cool overlay in the browser (Chrome).

How can i achieve this overlay in android, what methods, intends do need?

Please give me some advanced advice.

[image]

Comment: You want to create 3 floating action buttons on the bottom of the screen that overlays the webview?

Comment: Yes the 3 actions buttons. But i'm surfing in my Browser, click "share" (but  never leave the browser) and then the action buttons appear. I think internally an intent is sent to the app, and the app sends something like OK, now display the overlay in the browser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10267371/4907293